# Sequelize return type of increment method is not according to its definition

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

Here is the definition of increment method:

```
  static increment<M extends Model>(
    this: ModelStatic<M>,
    fields: AllowReadonlyArray<keyof Attributes<M>>,
    options: IncrementDecrementOptionsWithBy<Attributes<M>>
  ): Promise<[affectedRows: M[], affectedCount?: number]>;
  static increment<M extends Model>(
    this: ModelStatic<M>,
    fields: { [key in keyof Attributes<M>]?: number },
    options: IncrementDecrementOptions<Attributes<M>>
  ): Promise<[affectedRows: M[], affectedCount?: number]>;
```

According to this return type should be an array.
But in the console
return type looks like this
`[ [ undefined, 2 ] ]`
The "inner" array is the return type by the definition, but it seems like we got another array that wraps it all. So if you had the same experience I appreciate if you can help me somehow.

I tried this

```
const [something] = await repoMethod.incremnet()
```

And the return is valid. But I am not happy with this since it is not according to definition of the method.